# Does $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ irreducible, imply $f(2x)$ also irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

It is well known that $f(x+a) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible when $f(x)$ is irreducible. I was wondering whether $f(2x)$ and in general whether $f(nx)$ is irreducible as well.

Though it is relatively easy to find counterexamples for $f(x^2)$ reducible with $f(x)$ irreducible (consider $f(x) = x^2+4$), I haven't been able to find counterexamples for $f(2x)$.

I tried to write $f(2x) = g(x)h(x)$ so that $f(x) = g(\frac{x}{2})h(\frac{x}{2})$ which are polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then if $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ then maybe somehow $g(\frac{x}{2})$ and $h(\frac{x}{2})$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ too?

Edit: by "irreducible" I meant that $f$ cannot be written as a product of two nonconstant polynomials.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Working inside $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, irreducibility of $f(x)$ is the same as that of $f(2x)$ because $2$ is a unit.  Working inside $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, both $2$ and $x$ are "irreducibles," so $f(x) = x$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(2x) = 2x = (2) \cdot (x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a nontrivial factorization into irreducibles.

Comment: If the polynomial has an even constant term, then $f(2x)$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Better add the definition of irreducibly

Comment: And add that you want to know whether $f(2\,x)$ is not factorizable over $\mathbb{Z}$ as a product of nonconstant polynomials

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It makes a difference if you are considering irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

A counterexample for the first case: $f(x) = x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but $f(2x) = 2\cdot x$ is not.

In the second case your statement is true for all $n\neq 0$, since then $n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, so $f(x)\mapsto f(nx)$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

**UPDATE**

After giving this answer,the following was added to the question

> Edit: by "irreducible" I meant that f cannot be written as a product of two nonconstant polynomials.

First of all, this is a bit unfortunate, since it differs from the [established definition of irreducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) in ring theory.

However by [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29), it turns out that your notion of "irreducibility" of a polynomial $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ is exactly the same as the irreducibility of $f$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$, which is covered by the above discussion.

Comment: From Wikipedia: If F is a field, a non-constant polynomial is irreducible over F if cannot be factored into the product of two non-constant polynomials with coefficients in F

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes! But $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field!

Comment: Its obvious he wants non-constant polynomials

Comment: @EugenCovaci: No, this it is not obvious at all, since the question is about the ring $\mathbb Z[x]$. Anyway, I've added a discussion of the case that irreducibility was (tacitly) considered in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Irreducibility was not considered in Q[x]

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Then the definition of irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ applies and the counterexample is valid.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: By the way: Note that for $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$, the statements "$f$ is not the product of two non-constant polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$" and "$f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$" are the same.

Comment: @azimut Could you explain why "$f$ is not the product of two non-cosntant polynomials in \mathbb{Z}[x]" and "$f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are the same statement?

Comment: @Linus: [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

Comment: @LinusS. I've updated my answer. The pointer of Jyrki is the right one (of course), and yes, Gauss' Lemma is not a trivial one and needs a bit of work.

Comment: @azimut: Thank you. This is a mistake on my part - I received the problem originally saying "$f$ cannot be written as a product of two nonconstant polynomials" and interpreted this as "irreducible".